# I hear weird noise while acceleration. Is it normal?

Tags: noise, transmission

I don't want to describe what I hear, so I've recorded it. Here's the link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/78wfgeng2j6a0zk/Engine.mp4?dl=0#
You can hear it at 0:03 and 0:05 when the transmission shifts the gears. It only occurs if the RPM is not too high or not too low. Maybe at around 3-4000 RPM.
It is 150 HP TFSI engine with an s-tronic transmission.

Comment: Same noise as here: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/82995/10976

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is this noise at high rpm?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/82995/what-is-this-noise-at-high-rpm)

Comment: That was my question. I deleted it, because it wasn't accurate enough.

Comment: Instead of deleting the question, edit it and improve it.

Comment: So, to verify, in your audio clip at those times, your transmission shifted two times within 2 seconds of each shift? Or did you just paste two separate audio clips together?

Comment: Yes, it shifted two times. This is the original record, I didn't paste two separate audio together.